# How many choices do we have, when we choose $i $ edges from a complete bipartite graph such that none of the two selected edges has a common vertex?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider that we have a complete bipartite graph  with $2n $  vertices. In each part of this graph we have $n $  vertices. We want to choose $i\leq n$ edges of this graph such that  none of the two selected  edges has a common vertex.

How many choices do we have?

For example, when $i=n$, we have $n!$ choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\dbinom{n}{i}$ ways to choose $i$ points on one side of the bipartite graph for the edges to begin. After you've chosen these, there are $\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}$ ways to choose the $i$ distinct points on the other side that the edges on the first side connect to. So in total, there are $\dbinom{n}{i}\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}$ ways for this to occur.